# SQL Memory not exceeding 1.5 GB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, memory, 64-bit, ram

I'm running SQL 2008 R2 64 Bit on a Windows 2008 64 bit OS server.

The server has 7.5 GB RAM.

SQL Management Studio, connected to server, right click on server > Properties > Memory 
- Use AWE is unchecked
- Minimum server memory is 2000 (MB)
- Maximum server memory is 4000 (MB)
- Index Creation memory is 0 (KB)
- Minimum memory per query is 1024 (KB)

Task Manager > Processes > sqlservr.exe : it will slowly grow in size of total memory used, but NEVER exceeds ~1.5 GB in memory usage

This is confusing me: why would this not start at 2 GB used and slowly grow to 4 GB used, per the memory properties of the sql database server I have set up?

Note: I have restarted the SQL Server and it has had no effect on the memory usage.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you state what edition of SQL Server you are using ?
SQL Server Express places a limit on the buffer pool memory of 1GB, which accounts only for some of the overall process memory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Crap! That explains it! Using Express. Thank you!

Comment: I am having the same issue going on. Your answer makes sense, but I don't see any logical way to explain how memory usage goes beyond 1GB to ~1.5GB? This is annoying. Do you have any idea?

Comment: And I have a 4 core cpu, I understand that express can only use one of them and it uses it to its limit(%25) too. And even if I close the appliciations that use the db, the sql server still works up to 1.5gb and in a little while it crashes. What is going on here?

Comment: @Tolga. From what I understand, the 1GB limit is on data pages only (or buffer pool memory). The memory of the process you are seeing is made up of the data pages plus the engine code, bringing the total memory up to about 1.5GB

Comment: That's what I had in mind actually. So I see that this is normal behaviour of sql server. But is it normal that applications using that db crash with exception 'There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.'? I wasn't like that yesterday, and there is no increase in penetration or codes.